# Can we use the planets and Sun to fling out a craft at relativistic speeds?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, newtonian-gravity, orbital-motion, celestial-mechanics, escape-velocity

E.g. The Voyager crafts took various assists from the planets. Sun being much more massive, wouldn't a spacecraft gain much more energy from such a flyby on the correct trajectory? If so then what fraction of $c$ could we achieve?

Comment: Voting to close, sorry, this is a duplicate of http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/128356/ also related to http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/134473/

Comment: @count_to_10 I agree. Shall I delete this?

Comment: Sorry about that, been there myself,  imo yes, but it takes 5 votes so it's up to you.