# Thermonuclear propulsion in space, colliding hydrogen pellets on counter-rotating orbits

Tags: nuclear-physics, interstellar-travel

What if we send a swarm of tiny space-crafts contaning pellets of hydrogen (e.g. deuterium) in shells (I guess metallic) to elliptical counter-rotating orbits around the Sun (or another massive object, e.g. like Jupiter), setting precise timing and location where they collide one by one (pair by pair, around perihelion). So it will blow up right behind our another bigger spacecraft, which we can possibly accelerate and send this way to an interstellar travel.

The question is: Is the accumulated kinetic energy by the tiny space crafts set to an orbit going to be possibly enough, to collide the pellets so hard, that there is enough compression and temperature for the thermonuclear reaction to occur?

Comment: If this works out, 
I'm ready for some credits. 
Call it Artemenko Evgenii's trampoline :)

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that interplanetary speeds are on the order of tens of kilometres per second, while [the necessary speed to get proton-proton fusion is about 7% of lightspeed](https://dothemath.ucsd.edu/2012/01/nuclear-fusion/).

What about "easy" D-T fusion, which happens at a mere 45 million K? I get a [thermal velocity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thermal_velocity) of 431 km/s. This is less than I expected, but still about galactic escape velocity.

So sadly the trampoline method is unlikely to work.

Comment: Yeah, sad ))) but what if there is some kind of metallic shell which also compresses hydrogen upon a collision, maybe this helps ))

Comment: Though I googled out, that the Sun escape velocity is 615 km/sec, so maybe very long elliptical orbit works for Deuterium+Tritium ?)

Comment: @ЕвгенийАртеменко - A compressive shell will likely have to do most of the work rather than the orbital velocity. Gravitational slingshots at best give you 80 km/s https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/128356/gravitational-slingshot-maximum in the solar system - the sun is hard to use for this since you are already co-moving to a great extent, which means it is hard to drop in and get that yummy escape velocity that would indeed ignite the pellet.

Comment: Maybe we can somehow accumulate the velocity? We only need the 431 km/s around a perehelion.

Comment: Do you think the compressive shells are feasible? I just don't know enough physics to check if it is feasible at all to compress the hydrogen at a collision to ignite it. I guess I need to remember the collision is very short-term.